# C# - Serial communication with Agilent 34970A

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to communicate with an Agilent 34970A throw RS-232 with C#.

So far I tried this code but I can't stablish communication

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Ivi.Visa;
using Ivi.Visa.FormattedIO;

//using SerialInterface;
//using SerialInterface.RS232;
using System.IO.Ports;


namespace Serial_Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set address
            string VISA_ADDRESS = "ASRL9::INSTR";

            // Create a connection (session) to the RS-232 device.                                 
            IMessageBasedSession session = GlobalResourceManager.Open(VISA_ADDRESS) as IMessageBasedSession;

            // Enable the Termination Character.                
            session.TerminationCharacterEnabled = true;


            // Connection parameters
            ISerialSession serial = session as ISerialSession;
            serial.BaudRate = 9600;
            serial.DataBits = 8;
            serial.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serial.FlowControl = SerialFlowControlModes.DtrDsr;

            // Send the *IDN? and read the response as strings
            MessageBasedFormattedIO formattedIO = new MessageBasedFormattedIO(session);
            formattedIO.WriteLine("*IDN?");
            string idnResponse = formattedIO.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("*IDN? returned: {0}", idnResponse);

            // Close the connection to the instrument
            session.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an exception saying "Failed to parse ASRL9::INSTR in Ivi.Visa.GlobalResourceManager.Parse(...)"
So it means the problem comes from the following line of code:
                IMessageBasedSession session = GlobalResourceManager.Open(VISA_ADDRESS) as IMessageBasedSession;

I don't know how to solve this problem.
Is there any other way to connect to an Agilent via serial port and send SCPI commands?

Comment: Are you sure the resource name is "ASRL9::INSTR" ? You could try using the Find method to find all resources.

Comment: I have the same problem...Is like I can't use those methods. I wrote:

            IMessageBasedSession ports =  GlobalResourceManager.Find() as IMessageBasedSession;
            Console.WriteLine($" {ports} ");

And I get "Failed to find resources matching ?*"

Comment: Have you got all of the appropriate drivers for the 34970A installed correctly (including the prerequisite drivers)? This page links to the drivers & also gives C# programming examples https://www.keysight.com/main/techSupport.jspx?cc=GB&lc=eng&nid=-33261.536881544&pid=1000001313%3Aepsg%3Apro&pageMode=DS

Comment: I think is a problem with dll and it's something that a lot of people has commented already but I can't see the solution.The library "Ivi.Visa.Interop" is not working as expected. 
There are 2 in my PC, one un C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64 ..\5.5.0.0 and an other in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32 ..\5.5.0.0 ...when I add the dll to References in Visual Studio 2017 i get the next message:

Comment: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Ivi.Visa.Interop,Version=5.5.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=a128c98f1d7717c1, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures.Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your projct through the Configurtion Managr so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references,or take a dependency on referencs with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture

Comment: Well the error messages do give you some very specific information about what to look for? Is your project configured for x86 while using a 64bit dll? is Is AMD64 appropriate for your PC or should you be using a 32bit version?

Answer (score 0):

i worked with this name space

```
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;
```

i create 2 properties

```
//Open up a new resource manager
    private static ResourceManager _rm;

    //Open a new Formatted IO 488 session 
    private static FormattedIO488 _instr;
```

and then i open the instrument

```
public string OpenInstrument()
    {
        try
        {
            //Open up a handle to the instrument with a iTimeOut second timeout
            _instr.IO = (IMessage)_rm.Open(instrumentAdress, AccessMode.NO_LOCK, iTimeOut, "");


            //Reset the device
            _instr.WriteString("*RST", true);

            //Check if any error exist 
            return CheckPSError(_instr) ? "true" : "false";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Open Instrument exception : " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

for each command i check if there is errors reported by the instrument

```
private bool CheckPSError(FormattedIO488 instr)
    {
        instr.WriteString("SYST:ERR?", true);
        string errStr = instr.ReadString();

        if (errStr.Contains("No error"))
            //If no error, then return
            return true;
        //If there is an error, read out all of the errors and return them in an exception
        else
        {
            string errStr2 = "";
            do
            {
                instr.WriteString("SYST:ERR?", true);
                errStr2 = instr.ReadString();
                if (!errStr2.Contains("No error")) errStr = errStr + "\n" + errStr2;

            } while (!errStr2.Contains("No error"));
            throw new Exception("Exception: Encountered system error(s)\n" + errStr);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have a lot of problems with using Ivi.Visa.Interop;.....is like it doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem too when trying to use the `Ivi.Visa` which is located `"C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\Microsoft.NET\FrameworkXX\vxxxx\VISA.NET Shared Components xxx\Ivi.Visa.dll"` in the VB.NET. I get the exception:

```
Ivi.Visa.VisaException: Failed to parse ASRL1::INSTR at Ivi.Visa.GlobalResourceManager.Parse(String resourceName, SrmDictionary srms)
```

The main reason is the `Ivi.Visa` is platform-dependent and version dependent. That is even if you can run the program on computer A, but when you run the program on another computer with different versions of VISA installed, the exception will occur.
The right way is to use the `Ivi.Visa.Interop` as [@Erwin Draconis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2760650/erwin-draconis) points out, which is located `"C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\VisaComXXX\Primary Interop Assemblies\Ivi.Visa.Interop.dll"`, it is [Component Object Model (COM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) and compatible with other version VISA.
The code below works well for me(HP33401A, RS232). You can modify it to C# version.

```
Imports Ivi.Visa.Interop
Module Test_IVI_VISA_INTEROP_Serial
    Sub Main()
        Dim VISA_Address As String = "ASRL21::INSTR" 
        Dim _session As Ivi.Visa.Interop.IMessage
        Dim _serial_session As Ivi.Visa.Interop.ISerial
        Dim _Encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)
        Try
            _session = (New Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManager).Open(VISA_Address, Ivi.Visa.Interop.AccessMode.EXCLUSIVE_LOCK, 5000)
            _session.TerminationCharacterEnabled = True
            _session.TerminationCharacter = &HA
            _session.SendEndEnabled = False
            _session.Timeout = Convert.ToUInt32(5000)
            If _session.HardwareInterfaceType = Ivi.Visa.Interop.HardwareInterfaceType.INTF_ASRL Then
                _serial_session = CType(_session, Ivi.Visa.Interop.ISerial)
                _serial_session.EndIn       = Ivi.Visa.Interop.SerialEndConst.ASRL_END_NONE
                _serial_session.EndOut      = Ivi.Visa.Interop.SerialEndConst.ASRL_END_NONE
                _serial_session.BaudRate    = Convert.ToUInt32(9600)
                _serial_session.DataBits    = 8
                _serial_session.StopBits    = Ivi.Visa.Interop.SerialStopBits.ASRL_STOP_ONE
                _serial_session.FlowControl = Ivi.Visa.Interop.SerialFlowControl.ASRL_FLOW_NONE
                _serial_session.Parity      = Ivi.Visa.Interop.SerialParity.ASRL_PAR_NONE
            End If
            Dim cmd_string  As String = "*IDN?" + vbCrLf
            Dim ResponseBuffer As Byte()
            _session.Write(_Encoding.GetBytes(cmd_string),cmd_string.Length) 
            ResponseBuffer = _session.Read(UInt16.MaxValue)
            Console.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "    Send SCPI Command:" + cmd_string)
            Console.Write(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "    Get Response     :" + _Encoding.GetString(ResponseBuffer))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "    " + ex.ToString())
        End Try
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

[image: Test Result]